# JavaScript: Comparing arrays of objects with nested array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-filter

I would like to compare the `var arrayB` with `var arrayA` in the said condition as `arrayA[n].[m].id` will be matched with `arrayB[ele].optionValue[e].id`.

```js
var arrayA = [
[{value: "#0767b9", id: 162,productId: 1}, value: "#f4b7d4",id: 164,productId: 1],
[{value: "#44acd8",id: 102,productId: 2}],
[{value: "#609923",id: 106,productId: 3}, {value: "#ee3b70",id: 107,productId: 3}]
]
```

```js
var arrayB = [
    {
        id: 1, 
        optionValue: [{value: "#002e63",id: 161,productId: 1}, {value: "#0767b9",id: 162,productId: 1},{value: "#010b1d",id: 163,productId: 1}, {value: "#f4b7d4",id: 164,productId: 1}]
    },
    {
        id: 2, 
        optionValue: [{value: "#EC7063",id: 93,productId: 2}, {value: "#bf0000",id: 94,productId: 2}, {value: "#44acd8",id: 102,productId: 2}, {value: "#ffdbdb",id: 103,productId: 2}]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        optionValue: [{value: "#d861bd",id: 105,productId: 3}, {value: "#609923",id: 106,productId: 3}, {value: "#ee3b70",id: 107,productId: 3}]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        optionValue: [{value: "#44acd8",id: 165,productId: 4}]
    }
]
```

My goal is to return `var arrayB` with that filtered data that will remove the object which is not in the `var arrayA`, like this:

```js
var result = [
    {
        id: 1, 
        optionValue: [{value: "#0767b9",id: 162,productId: 1},{value: "#f4b7d4",id: 164,productId: 1}]
    },
    {
        id: 2, 
        optionValue: [{value: "#44acd8",id: 102,productId: 2}]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        optionValue: [{value: "#609923",id: 106,productId: 3},{value: "#ee3b70",id: 107,productId: 3}]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        optionValue: [{value: "#44acd8",id: 165,productId: 4}]
    }
]
```

I have workaround as below but that is not giving the desired output.

```js
const myArray = arrayB.map((el) => {
  el.optionValue.filter((fl) => {
    arrayA.map(values => {
      values.map((value) => {
        !value.id.includes(fl.id)
      }) 
    })
  })
});
```

Note: For `id:4` in result set is the case that is the selected productId for which there is no any value is selected. So in arrayA there is no value for `productId:4`. So in result for this kind of cases if there is no values are for comparison then it should be return as it is instead of blank array.

Comment: why do you have `id: 4` in the result set?

Comment: That is the selected productId for which there is no any value is selected. So in `arrayA` there is no value for `productId:4`... so in result for this kind of cases if there is no values are for comparison then it should be return as it is instead of blank array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to get only common identifier pairs from both, you could collect the identifier and map the filterd array of `arrayB`.

This approach takes only one loop for every array.

```js
const
    arrayA = [[{ value: "#0767b9", id: 162, productId: 1 }, { value: "#f4b7d4", id: 164, productId: 1 }], [{ value: "#44acd8", id: 102, productId: 2 }], [{ value: "#609923", id: 106, productId: 3 }, { value: "#ee3b70", id: 107, productId: 3 }]],
    arrayB = [{ id: 1, optionValue: [{ value: "#002e63", id: 161, productId: 1 }, { value: "#0767b9", id: 162, productId: 1 }, { value: "#010b1d", id: 163, productId: 1 }, { value: "#f4b7d4", id: 164, productId: 1 }] }, { id: 2, optionValue: [{ value: "#EC7063", id: 93, productId: 2 }, { value: "#bf0000", id: 94, productId: 2 }, { value: "#44acd8", id: 102, productId: 2 }, { value: "#ffdbdb", id: 103, productId: 2 }] }, { id: 3, optionValue: [{ value: "#d861bd", id: 105, productId: 3 }, { value: "#609923", id: 106, productId: 3 }, { value: "#ee3b70", id: 107, productId: 3 }] }, { id: 4, optionValue: [{ value: "#44acd8", id: 165, productId: 4 }] }],
    identifiers = arrayA.reduce((r, a) => {
        a.forEach(({ id, productId }) => (r[productId] = r[productId] || {})[id] = true);
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = arrayB.map(o => identifiers[o.id]
        ? { ...o, optionValue: o.optionValue.filter(({ id, productId }) => identifiers[productId][id]) }
        : o
    );

   console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes it is almost nearest to the what I am looking for. Do review the update question with Note that in result `id:4` will be also there if no matches is found.

Comment: By running this code into my Angular project it throws me an error like `error TS1005: ':' expected`. 
My typescript version is `2.9.2`

Comment: maybe you need to replace `(r[id] ??= {})[productId] = true` with `(r[id] = r[id] || {})[productId] = true`

Comment: By replacing with the updated condition the result is giving the wrong result, can you pls check ?

Comment: i get the same result, please see above.

Comment: Pls review sir, my actual code and data that i am getting in the result... I am not figure out what I am doing wrong. 
https://prnt.sc/wlnrfz
https://prnt.sc/wlns8e

Comment: maybe `id` from the second array is not given or has a different property name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227188/discussion-between-tma-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 1):

Can try out with this:

```js
var arrayA = [
    [{value: "#0767b9", id: 162, productId: 1}, {value: "#f4b7d4", id: 164, productId: 1}],
    [{value: "#44acd8", id: 102, productId: 2}],
    [{value: "#609923", id: 106, productId: 3}, {value: "#ee3b70", id: 107, productId: 3}]
];

var arrayB = [
    {
        id: 1,
        optionValue: [{value: "#002e63", id: 161, productId: 1}, {
            value: "#0767b9",
            id: 162,
            productId: 1
        }, {value: "#010b1d", id: 163, productId: 1}, {value: "#f4b7d4", id: 164, productId: 1}]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        optionValue: [{value: "#EC7063", id: 93, productId: 2}, {
            value: "#bf0000",
            id: 94,
            productId: 2
        }, {value: "#44acd8", id: 102, productId: 2}, {value: "#ffdbdb", id: 103, productId: 2}]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        optionValue: [{value: "#d861bd", id: 105, productId: 3}, {
            value: "#609923",
            id: 106,
            productId: 3
        }, {value: "#ee3b70", id: 107, productId: 3}]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        optionValue: [{value: "#44acd8", id: 165, productId: 4}]
    }
];
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++) {
    let selectedElem = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < arrayB[i].optionValue.length; j++) {
        arrayA.forEach(elemA => {

            elemA.forEach(subElemA => {
                if(subElemA.id === arrayB[i].optionValue[j].id) {
                    selectedElem.push(arrayB[i].optionValue[j]);
                }
            })
        })
    }
    if (selectedElem.length !== 0){
        arrayB[i].optionValue = selectedElem;
    }
    result.push(arrayB[i]);
}
console.log('result::', JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: Do review the update question with Note that in result id:4 will be also there if no matches is found.